# bash Shell scripting: how to read a file line by line and pass to a variable

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a file named `a1.txt` that contain different `filesystems(paths)` listed in it:

```
//abc/dds
//abc/abc
```

Now I need to write a script in path `//abc` that will read the content of `a1.txt` line by line. For every line read from this file I need to execute the command `ls -lat line_read_from_file|tail -10>filename.txt`

At the same time I need the different file to be created for every line read from `a1.txt`.

Can someone write a script for this?

Comment: did you tried any sample code? where you struck?

Comment: You need to start writing it yourself. When you are stuck people will help you.

Comment: Well StackOverflow is not a place where you can book a script... You should try by yourself and describe your trials to us first.

Comment: "can someone write a script for this?" Yes, you can. We believe in you !

Comment: i have tried the below script #!/bin/bash file=/abc/a1.txt                  while IFS='' read line;   do done<$file

Comment: @SandeshKumar, could you edit your question, by adding your script.

Comment: @SandeshKumar you need to put a semicolon before `done` to indicate the end of the body of `while`. `while IFS='' read line; do <commands>; done<$file`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do something per each line in a text file, you can do something like below.

```
while read -r line; do ls -lat $line | tail -10>output_file.txt; done < a1.txt
```

Since I don't clearly understand your requirement, you may have to improve this to fit your needs.

EDIT:

Seems like you are trying to put the last 10 lines of each file listed in `a1.txt` into separate files.

```
index=1 && while read -r line; tail -10 $line >> file_${index} && index=$((index+1)); done < a1.txt
```

Comment: i have tried the below script #!/bin/bash file=/abc/a1.txt                           while IFS=' ' read line;   do     ls -lat $line|tail -10>/abc/filename.txt           done<$file                                                                                                              but this is not creating any file

Comment: you need a semicolon before done; `while IFS=' ' read line; do ls -lat $line|tail -10>/abc/filename.txt; done<$file`

Comment: Thanks Anubis I will try this

Comment: At the same time I want to create a file for every line read. For example say that there are 10 Lines in the file,  for every line I want to create 10 different files with names like filename0.txt, filename1.txt, .........,filename9.txt

Comment: I have tried putting semicolon. I have tried commands inside and out of while loop, found that the control is not going inside while loop.

Comment: what actually I am trying: a1.txt contains some lines. i want to read line one> do ls -lat LINE1|tail -10> put output to file1.txt Similarly read line2>do ls -lat LINE2|tail -10>put output to file2.txt and so on

Comment: What are you trying to do with `ls -lat <filename> | tail -10`? it will just display the result of `ls -lat <filename>`. Please try first and ask if you are unclear of something. Seems like you are not putting any effort and expecting someone to do your work instead?